# Get JSON code from Textarea and parse it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON code inside a textarea and I want to get it and work with it as it is exist in my website.

This is the textarea code :

```
<textarea>
  var settings = [
        {
            "id" : "post_thumbnail",
            "name" : "Default Post Thumbnail",
            "desc" : "The image src that you want to use for non-thumbnail posts.", 
            "type" : "text",
            "std" : "http://lorempixel.com/640/300/"
        }
    ]
</textarea>
```

I tried this but unfortunately it work only if the code exist in the website not in textarea because I get this error :

Uncaught ReferenceError: settings is not defined

```
for( var i = 0; i < settings.length; i++){

        var setting_id = settings[i].id,
            setting_name = settings[i].name,
            setting_desc = settings[i].desc,
            setting_type = settings[i].type,
            setting_std = settings[i].std;
$('body').html(setting_id +'<br>'+ setting_name +'<br>'+ setting_desc +'<br>'+ setting_type +'<br>'+  setting_std);
}
```

This is a live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/tauv0or1/

Comment: That is not JSON, it is JavaScript. Admittedly, if you remove the `=` and everything before it than *what is left* is JSON.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for your reply. Excuse me I'm a biginner and I thought that we call this JSON.
So what can I do to get what I want ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The value of `textarea` does not get parsed as JavaScript. Instead, change the value to valid JSON:

```
<textarea>
    [
        {
            "id" : "post_thumbnail",
            "name" : "Default Post Thumbnail",
            "desc" : "The image src that you want to use for non-thumbnail posts.", 
            "type" : "text",
            "std" : "http://lorempixel.com/640/300/"
        }
    ]
</textarea>
```

And tweak your JavaScript to use `JSON.parse` on the value:

```
var field = document.getElementById("the_textarea");
var settings = JSON.parse(field.value);
```

Because the user can enter arbitrary information into the textarea, you might want to wrap `JSON.parse` in a try-catch block, and alert the user to a syntax error:

```
var settings = null;

try {
    settings = JSON.parse(field.value);
}
catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof SyntaxError) {
        alert("There was a syntax error. Please correct it and try again: " + error.message);
    }
    else {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to eval the text first to actually run it as javascript:

```
eval($('textarea').text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tauv0or1/1/

Alternatively, you can parse it as JSON, but you need to edit the contents of the textarea first:

```
var settings = JSON.parse($('textarea').text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tauv0or1/2/

Comment: Most likely because you are using `eval`

Comment: Could a downvoter please explain? `eval()` is scary and bad, but it's actually the only way to evaluate the `textarea` content *as-is*.

Comment: @GregBurghardt `eval` is bad practice but it shouldn't be an automatic downvote in cases where it is a viable solution.

Comment: @JamesBrierley: I agree that `eval` is not universally bad (BTW I was not the downvoter). You were merely trying to fix the OP's original issue where they wanted to parse the textarea value as-is and not change their JavaScript code -- in which case `eval` would work, albeit bad practice.